# Leveling in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, levels

I'm new at programming and don't know how to make a level counter that can be accessed in every scene.

I created a 3D game.  When the player has completed level 1, then I want level 2 to be unlocked using this method:

When the player has completed the level, the value of the level counter changes to 2  and the trigger can access that level counter.

**The below is not my code, but is just there to make it more clear:**

```
var level = "level counter which is 2 in this case"
if level == 3
active the trigger (trigger teleports the player to level 3)
else {
floatMessage("You haven't finished level (?) yet.")
}
```

Comment: look at singletons, dontdestroyonload .. this will mean you have an object that perpetuates irrelevant of scene loading with values on that will remain.  You then put one in every scene so you can scene test as the singleton will ditch any spare that tries to make itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a persistance system.

There are many ways to save your game state. The easiest and most accessible remains the PlayerPrefs, although it is not optimal for more complex saves.

You could save your amount of levels unlocked (assuming it is incremental) by using this call :

```
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelsUnlocked", 3);
```

and then you can retrieve the value by using :

```
levelsUnlocked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked", 0);
```

**Note** : The second parameter here is a default value assigned in case you haven't saved before.

Hope it helps. If you're looking to upgrade your save game, consider writing your own save file class and serialize it using JSON. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

The former option remains convenient for a simple project.

Comment: While PlayerPrefs is technically a valid solution, PlayerPrefs should be restricted for player preferences only. Things like "enable screen shake", "color blind mode", and "Volume levels" are considered preferences. Game progress like a level counter is not a preference.

Comment: Absolutely. This is why I never use it personally. But for a quick implementation it can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle this. My recommendation is to store game progress data to a file or database outside the scope of the scene (a good file-based DB solution is SQLite - [here](https://github.com/ErikOverflow/YardDefender/wiki/Saving-Game-Data-to-SQLite)'s a wiki post I made on how I implemented SQLite in one of my recent projects).

However, if you only wish game progress to persist during the life of the game (it always starts at level 1 when you start it), then Singletons and DontDestroyOnLoad are also a good solution, as @BugFinder mentioned.

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static LevelManager instance;
    public static LevelManager Instance { get => instance; }

    int levelNum = 1;
    public int LevelNum { get => levelNum; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        //Check to see if an instance of the LevelManager already exists.
        if(instance != null && instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameobject);
    }

    public void LevelComplete()
    {
        levelNum++;
    }
}
```

As long as the above code is attached to a gameobject in your scene, you can call the following from another gameobject's script. You will notice that I encapsulate levelNum and instance. This is to enforce good practice in my other code. I know that the only script that can modify levelNum or instance is LevelManager, so I won't accidentally break something by changing one of those values in another script accidentally.

Be careful to only put the above script on a gameobject that is allowed to persist between scenes. I like to create an empty "Singletons" gameobject that just holds my singletons.

Example usage when defeating the final boss (if that's a way to beat your levels):

```
void BossDefeated()
{
    LevelManager.Instance.LevelComplete();
}
```

Example usage when checking to see if a portal can be opened:

```
int portalNum = 3;
bool CheckPortal()
{
    if(LevelManager.Instance.LevelNum >= portalNum)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you just use a Static int if you just want something quick:

```
public static int level;
```

Then from anywhere, call the class name i.e. LevelManager.level;

If you want to have it trigger something, you are better off having a callback of some sort, and making it private with a public get, which in turn calls something like a UnityEvent. This answer will probably not be very popular, but it is quick to do :)

Comment: While this is technically allowed, this has similar downfalls to using PlayerPrefs. The value being set is not tied to a runtime gameobject, so there will be hidden dependencies on initializing and managing the value.

Comment: Agree it is not ideal, but the poster is new to programming and I did not want to daunt him with a Singleton, the chances of this impact being a problem for a new coder in my mind is slim. @ErikOverflow, as a member with a much higher status on this platform, is it better to always provide a more complex cast iron solution with the downside of creating a high barrier to entry for new users?

Comment: It's typically better received to provide a best-practice solution. If your solution is not best practice and is aimed towards a less-advanced userbase, then it's usually a good idea to state "This is not best practice, but is the lowest-effort way to solve your problem." You stated "This answer will not be very popular", but that's not indicative of best-practice.